# Angular JS Select menu from data, keep 1 item at top?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, forms

I have an ng-repeat select menu of countries of the world, their names and 2-letter abbreviations.

I know from the Angular docs you can hard-code 1 `option` item before your `ng-repeat` in a select menu (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/select)

So, as intended I used this for a null value "Choose..." menu item.

The rest of the items come from a JSON source, alphabetized in my service by country code.

Now my client wants to have the United States at the top of the menu, since it's chosen most often (and a British version with UK at top).

How can I accomplish this, short of re-ordering my JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the orderBy filter in Angular (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Because orderBy can only be used with a predicate function or expression, you cannot write your own comparison function, but you could force making US or UK first by returning a value that will be in front of every others.

For example, if each country has an ID, and you have something like Afghanistan (ID = 1), Albania (ID = 2) ... and US (ID = 200), then your predicate could look like this:

```
$scope.predicate = function (country) {
    if (country.Name == 'United States') return -1;
    else return country.ID;
}
```

And then use your predicate in your ng-repeat like this

```
ng-repeat="country in countries | orderBy:predicate"
```

This works because (according to the docs)

> the result of this function will be sorted using the <, =, > operator.

If you don't have an ID, you could force the ordering using any other property that sorts using the comparison operators above.

Comment: Thanks.  Out of curiosity, why do many people (like yourself) omit parens these days on if/then/else statements? This was a big help I was unaware I could cosnstruct a predicate like this.